# How to read .csv-data containing thousand separators and special handling of zeros (in R)?

Tags: r, csv, zero

R version 3.2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

I am trying to read in R .csv-data (two columns: "id" and "variable1") containing the thousand separator ",". 
So far no problem. I am using read.csv2 and the data looks like that:

```
> data <- read.csv2("data.csv", sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, dec = ".")
> data[1000:1010, ]
     id        variable1
         1     2,001
     1,001     2,002
     1,002     2,001
     1,003     2,002
     1,004     2,001
     1,005     2,002
     1,006     2,001
     1,007     2,002
     1,008     2,001
     1,009     2,002
      1,01     2,001
```

After that first I tried to use gsub() to remove the commas:

```
data[, c("id", "variable1")] <- sapply(data[, c("id", "variable1")],
          function(x) {as.numeric(gsub("\\,","", as.character(x)))})
> data[1000:1010, ]
     id      variable1
        1      2001
     1001      2002
     1002      2001
     1003      2002
     1004      2001
     1005      2002
     1006      2001
     1007      2002
     1008      2001
     1009      2002
      101      2001
```

I think my problem is already obvious in the first output, because there is a thousand separator, but the "ending zeros" are missing. Like number "1000" is just displayed as "1"  and "1010" as "1,01" for the "id"-variable in the data (also in the .csv-data). Of course, R can't identify this.

So my question is: Is there are way to tell R that every number must have three numbers after the thousand separator when reading in the data (or maybe after that), so that I have the correct numbers?
The data should look like this:

```
> data[1000:1010, ]
     id      variable1
     1000      2001
     1001      2002
     1002      2001
     1003      2002
     1004      2001
     1005      2002
     1006      2001
     1007      2002
     1008      2001
     1009      2002
     1010      2001
```

**Edit:**
Thanks you all for your answers. Unfortunately the suggestions will work for this example but not for my data, because I think I chose bad example rows. Other rows in the data can look like this:

```
       id1 variable1
1        1     2,001
999    999     1,102
1000     1     2,001
1001 1,001     2,002
1002 1,002     2,001
```

Of course, there is twice the number "1". The first is really a "1", but the second should be a "1000". But now I think I can't solve my problem with R. Maybe I need a better export of the original data, because the problem appears also in the .csv data.

Comment: Can you read by specifying `colClasses=c('character', 'character')` in the `read.csv`?

Comment: No, the problem with the missing zeros appears already in the .csv-data. So of course I can't see the zeros in R, because they are not there. I am searching for a solution like "how to add" the zeros in R.

Comment: So, I guess the actual `1` and `1000`  would be just 1?

Comment: `read.csv2` should interpret the `,` as a decimal point, as these numbers appear to be. If it does interpret them as this you can multiply by 1000 to get your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "," is the only separator, i.e. all of the numbers are integers, you can set the `dec` argument of `csv2` (or `read.csv`) to "," and multiply by 1000:

```
data <- read.csv2(
  text = "id    ; variable1
          1     ; 2,001
          1,008 ; 2,001
          1,009 ; 2,002
          1,01  ; 2,001
          1,3   ; 2,0",
  sep = ";",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  header = TRUE,
  dec = "," )
```

.

```
> 1000*data
    id variable1
1 1000      2001
2 1008      2001
3 1009      2002
4 1010      2001
5 1300      2000
>
```

Answer (score 0):

after you removed the commas, you could do the following:

```
data$id <- data$id*(10^(4-nchar(data$id)))
```